# How do install a click handler on a dynamic listview (in tornadofx)

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

My application needs to permit additions to the listview. I've figured out how I can dynamically add to a listview by using `observableArrayList`. If I click on the button, an item gets added to the list and displayed.

Now I'm struggling to add a click handler (I want to handle the event that happens when someone clicks on any item within the list view). Where do I do this?

Here is my code.

```
package someapp

import javafx.collections.FXCollections
import javafx.geometry.Pos
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight
import tornadofx.*

class MyApp : App(HelloWorld::class) {
}

class HelloWorld : View() {
    val leftSide: LeftSide by inject()

    override val root = borderpane {
        left = leftSide.root
    }
}

class LeftSide: View() {

    var requestView: RequestView by singleAssign()

    override val root = VBox()

    init {
        with(root) {
            requestView = RequestView()
            this += requestView

            this += button("Add Item") {
                action {
                    requestView.responses.add( Request( "example.com",
                            "/foo/bar",
                            "{ \"foo\" : \"bar\"}".toByteArray()))
                }
            }

        }
    }

}


class RequestView : View() {

    val responses = FXCollections.observableArrayList<Request>(
    )

    override val root = listview(responses) {
        cellFormat {
            graphic = cache {
                form {
                    fieldset {
                        label(it.hostname) {
                            alignment = Pos.CENTER_RIGHT
                            style {
                                fontSize = 22.px
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.BOLD
                            }
                        }
                        field("Path") {
                            label(it.path)
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}

class Request(val hostname: String, val path: String, val body: ByteArray) {
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To configure a callback when an item in a ListView is selected, use the `onUserSelect` callback:

```
onUserSelect {
    information("You selected $it")
}
```

You can optionally pass how many clicks constitutes a select as well, default is 2:

```
onUserSelect(1) {
    information("You selected $it")
}
```

You are using some outdated constructs in your code, here is an updated version converted to best practices :)

```
class MyApp : App(HelloWorld::class)

class HelloWorld : View() {
    override val root = borderpane {
        left(LeftSide::class)
    }
}

class LeftSide : View() {
    val requestView: RequestView by inject()

    override val root = vbox {
        add(requestView)
        button("Add Item").action {
            requestView.responses.add(Request("example.com",
                    "/foo/bar",
                    """{ "foo" : "bar"}""".toByteArray()))
        }
    }
}


class RequestView : View() {
    val responses = FXCollections.observableArrayList<Request>()

    override val root = listview(responses) {
        cellFormat {
            graphic = cache {
                form {
                    fieldset {
                        label(it.hostname) {
                            alignment = Pos.CENTER_RIGHT
                            style {
                                fontSize = 22.px
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.BOLD
                            }
                        }
                        field("Path") {
                            label(it.path)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        onUserSelect(1) {
            information("You selected $it")
        }
    }

}

class Request(val hostname: String, val path: String, val body: ByteArray)
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. I'm very thankful to know about the best practices. With the new syntax, however, I'm now not entirely sure how I get references to views. For example, if I wanted to add a view to HelloWorld (in the right position), then how would I wire the `onUserSelect(1)` so that inside that I could talk to the right side view instance? I'm a little confused by the use of `::class` because I assume I would want a reference to the instance, not the class (which obviously happens under the hood, but I'm unclear how I reference the instantiated object, and from where (init?)).

Comment: Or, where is the new syntax documented?

Comment: This syntax is used all over the guide. If you find examples using out dated syntax, please file an issue with the guide project and we'll update it :)

Comment: So if I look for `left(LeftSide::class)` in the guide, I'll see examples? I think I was looking at the most recent examples but must be using an old guide. If I see outdated stuff, will file a bug.

Comment: I'm not sure if left() is covered in the guide, but we're grateful for all issues against the guide for outdated syntax for sure :)